# datastore index exception though I have defined index for the same

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity king `review` as follows properties and value

```
Review {
 merchantId : 'X',
 appId : 'Y',
 productId : 'Z',
 reviewId : '12345',
 timeStamp : '1493482784728',
 viewtimestamp : '148834892374'
}
```

and I have defined index as follows

```
<datastore-index kind="review" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="merchantId" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="appId" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="productId" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="reviewId" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="timeStamp" direction="desc"/>
        <property name="viewtimestamp" direction="desc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

And my query is as follows

```
SELECT reviewId FROM review WHERE merchantId = X AND appId = Y AND productId = Z;
```

When I execute this query I am getting following index sugession

```
<datastore-index kind="review" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="appId" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="merchantId" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="productId" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="reviewId" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Am I missing anything here? How the order get decided? Please help

Comment: The index do not work like this. You need to have specific indexes. Having a bigger index does not mean sub indexes will be handled automatically.

Comment: Yes, added another index comprising only querying fields and it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes don't behave that way. If the system cannot find your precise index for the query, it won't return.

Having a more complex index and trying to serve your query with that index means that the datastore would need to do some calculations instead of a straight up lookup. And datastore doesn't do that.

If you want your queries to go through AT ALL, you need indexes for them, or it just won't run. The ONLY difference is the [zigzag merge join algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofhEyDBpngM) that can help serve your queries if you DON'T have all the indexes. But you can't rely only on it, as it cannot serve everything, it needs partial indexes

Comment: So defining index based on each query is the right approach?

Comment: @Pokuri try using index auto generation, that should give you all indexes you need to perform whatever operations you are testing.

Comment: @jirungaray Yes, we can address this with auto generation enabled. But I marked it as false to make my team to write indexes based on queries. So, if a query works in devserver also works on cloud. Also I can have clear revision history for datastore-index.xml